# Awesomium browser and alignment differences on different machines

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, awesomium

I have an .Net application in which I use Awesomium browser and Microsoft Multipoint Mouse SDK. The problem is that Im getting a little bit different results when I run it on two different machines. In one machine I can see the scroll bars of the browser and my mouse alignment as I have configured it is perfect. But in the other machine the mouse alignment appears a bit different, the scroll bars do not appear and the browser is shifted a bit to the right... I tried but cannot figure what the problem might be. The two machines have a different screen size, the first one has a resolution of 1366x768 and the second one has a resolution of 1280x1024. Has this problem anything to do with the resolutions?

Comment: Do you have different display font sizes/scaling on the two computers?

Comment: Win 7: Control Panel/Display.  Should show a selected percentage (100, 125, 150).  If the selected % is are different on each computer, you'd likely have different scaling which could result in what you're seeing.  You can synchronize the % on each computer (and reboot) to verify that's the issue.  FWIW, I haven't see a single app on Windows that has a consistent display when that % isn't "default".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win 7: Control Panel/Display. Should show a selected percentage (100, 125, 150). If the selected % is are different on each computer, you'd likely have different scaling which could result in what you're seeing. You can synchronize the % on each computer (and reboot) to verify that's the issue. FWIW, I haven't see a single app on Windows that has a consistent display when that % isn't "default".